# groups and fields

Tags: abstract-algebra

So I am having trouble answering some of these questions.

1.$(\mathbb{C},+)$ is a group

2.$(\mathbb{C},\times)$ is a group

3.$(\mathbb{C}-\{0\},+)$ is a group

4.$(\mathbb{C}-\{0\},\times)$ is a group

5.$(\mathbb{C},+,\times)$ is a ring

6.$(\mathbb{C},+,\times)$ is a commutative ring with identity

7.$(\mathbb{C},+,\times)$ is a field

so far I have proved that 1, 4, 6, and 7 are true. However, I am having troubles with the rest but I think they are false. If anyone has any ideas for 2, 3, and 5, as in what properties do not hold. Also if someone can please verify that the ones i think are true are really true.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 1):

Numbers $2$ and $3$ are not true. The issue is invertibility and closure and the element $0 \in \Bbb C$. Some hints on the matter:

- What is the inverse of $0$ in $\Bbb C$ under $\times$? All elements of groups must have inverses. If you cannot show the existence of one for any particular element, no group. This gives you your counterexample for number $2$.
- Find complex numbers $w,z$ such that $w+z=0$. By finding such a pair, you don't even have a well-defined operation $+$ on $\Bbb C - \{0\}$. Thus, no group and your idea for problem $3$.

If you accept numbers $6$ and $7$ are true, however, you must also accept number $5$ is true. All commutative rings and fields are rings; that is, a field is a special type of ring with even stricter restrictions, and same for commutative rings (but looser restrictions than fields).

The rest are correct.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you mean. I read it as $(\Bbb C,+,\times)$ being a ring - which it is, is it not?

Comment: Yes i forgot the comma.